# Best practices for GPG user ids and mail extensions / catch-all addresses

Tags: email, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

Assuming I want to use different mail addresses for different purposes and using either a catch-all configuration (`*@example.com`) or mail extensions (e.g. `me+*@example.com`) (where `*` can be replaced with anything). But for simplicity and because of using a smartcard for enhanced GPG security, I want to use a single GPG key for all addresses possible. What is the best practice for that if there is one at all? Or have you any tips for that usecase?

I can think of following different ideas which all have huge downsites:

- Add a user id per mail used: This would require having a key with up to 100 different UIDs and it would be exposed to others which addresses I'm using.
- Configure a user id with `*@example.com`/`me+*@example.com`: This would allow to use a single ID and allow my recipients to understand, that I claim all possible addresses. However I expect that no current mail client is supporting that and so recipients will need to ignore multiple errors when writing with me.
- Configure a user id with an "example" address, e.g. `me@example.com`: Same problems as with the wildcard, but users would not have a chance to understand that I claim to control all addresses. However, it would look cleaner.

Comment: I don't think GPG can do this, but if all you want to do is sign outgoing mail, consider [DomainKeys Identified Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) (DKIM) instead.

Comment: I have just stumbled across this while configuring WKD for my mail pseudo-catch-all address. Option 3, the one I'm going with in combination with a WKS returning the same "default" key for all requests causes GPG to download the key but then still verify the keyid which fails. Option 3 does not integrate even with a custom WKS system and thus requires manual configuration for every person you exchange mail with (in part [because Thunderbird also requires special configuration to work with that](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/openpgp-recipient-alias-configuration)).